# SDL ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: sdl

im writing a sample SDL program, and I just wrote the simplest program, but i get the following error because of my SDL_pollevent() function:

```
Test.cpp:(.text._ZN4CApp9OnExecuteEv[CApp::OnExecute()]+0x41): undefined reference to `SDL_PollEvent'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and the code is:

```
int OnExecute()
{
    if(OnInit()==false)
        return -1;
    SDL_Event Event;
    while(Running)
    {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event))
        {
            OnEvent(&Event);
        }
            OnLoop();
        OnRend();
    }
    OnClean();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your linker command line?  Also, `SDL_PollEvent()` won't work too well without a `SDL_Init()` call somewhere before it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a linker error. You are not correctly linking the SDL libraries to your project. Usually you would need to add `-lSDL` to your linker. If you are using Windows I believe you have to add `-lSDLmain` too. Make sure your compiler knows where to find these files (set your library path correctly). If you don't know how to do this, check the system and IDE specific installation instructions in [this tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/index.php).

I assume that `SDL_Init()` is called within `OnInit()`? Otherwise your program will not run correctly.

Comment: Yo man thanks a lot, the -lSDL did the job. I can't thank you enough, this was bugging me for a reeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeally long time. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are including SDL.h, which will look like this on most platforms:

```
#include "SDL.h"
```

If you're building on a Mac with Xcode, you'll want to use this instead:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
```

Then make sure you've linked against the SDL framework:

- If you're using Visual Studio (Windows), right-click the project and bring up the Properties, then under Configuration Properties > Linker > Input, make sure Additional Dependencies is **SDL.lib SDLmain.lib**.
- If you're using Xcode (Mac), find SDL.framework (probably under /Library/Frameworks) and drag it to your project's Frameworks folder.
- If you're invoking GCC from the command-line, link to libSDL.a and libSDLmain.a by adding **-lSDL -lSDLmain** to your command-line.